# How do I avoid curving / pinching when using subdivision surface?

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface

[image]

When using subdivision surface, I get this weird curved edge geometry. This is along a mirrored split. How do I get this into a solid face again?

Comment: enable the Clipping option of the Mirror modifier? It makes the vertices merge along the mirror axis